# discharge of capacitor through a current source

Tags: capacitor, current, discharge

Assume we have a cap connected to a current source that draws a current \$I_0\$. What time would it take to discharge the cap by a voltage \$V_t\$?

$$t=\frac{C \times V_t}{I_0}$$

Is this correct or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, Q = I*t = C*V; so t = C*V/I.

Answer (score 2):

This is correct. The charge of the capacitor is given by:
$$Q=CV$$
and for constant current \$I\$, the charge is 
$$Q=I\cdot t$$
So $$CV=I\cdot t$$
which leads to $$t=\frac{CV}{I}$$